# Error when run docker-compose up

Tags: docker, laravel-5, docker-compose

I have a problem when I run command `docker-compose up` with laravel project. When I am running `docker-compose up` command, I am encountering following error.

`ERROR: Windows named pipe error: Access is denied. (code: 5)`,

What does this mean? Can any one help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of your docker compose file?

Comment: this is my docker-compose.yml https://gist.github.com/dunglv/22e61e14d14fddb79be9af7f2b2d164c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolve for this problem. At setup docker time, I have installed with admin role, so I have changed role when run app docker to administrator.